# Executing javascript function on AJAX success in WP

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a function in my Wordpress that regenerate Google Map.
What I want to achieve is to get some markers from my WP, then add them to DIV and generate from them map again.

For regenerating I'm using simple function with magic name "regenerate_map()" :) .

```
jQuery(".gmaps-button").click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data : {action: "jv_get_map_data", ids : 1},
        //data: dataString,
        action: 'jv_get_map_data',
        beforeSend:  function() {
            //jQuery('#contact-form #err2').html('').hide();
            //jQuery(".submit").html("proszę czekać").addClass('loading');


        },
        success: function(text) {
            jQuery('#gmaps-markers').html(text);
            console.log(text);
            regenerate_map();
        } 



    });

    return false;

});
```

The main problem is that function regenerate_map() is not working.
I get "ReferenceError: regenerate_map is not defined".
This is not true, because, I have other button, which is a trigger for click() and it uses this function also and it works.

I think that is something wrong with executing other function in AJAX request, but console.log and alert() works.

I thought that problem can be with what I get as "text" but I have checked that even if I get nothing, problem exists too.

Maybe some security issue?

Can somebody tell me why and what to do to achieve what I need?

Comment: Where is `regenerate_map()` defined? It is probably out of scope when you call it in the AJAX result handler. What Google Maps library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

your `regenerate_map()` function should be like this.

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           jQuery("#p_button").click ( function () {
           console.log("button got clicked");
           var donor_data= [ "12","13","14" ];
           var damount = 1234;
           var donor_obj = {
               id : donor_data,
               amnt : damount,
           };
           jQuery.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               //dataType : "json",
               url: "<?php echo  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>",
               data: { action : "ajx_add_donations",
                  'donors' :  JSON.stringify(donor_obj),
                 },
               success:function(response){
                   console.log("success " ,response);
                   //console.log("success " + JSON.parse(response));
                   //jQuery("#d_amount").val(donor_data[0]);
                   //jQuery("#p_button").text("brrr");
                    regenerate_map();
                },
               error: function(response) {
                   console.log("error" + response);
                  },
               });
               });
        });

        function  regenerate_map(){
            alert("test");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the same, I already figured it out. It was a problem with access to javascript function that I wanted to execute onsuccess.